# Join Two table in Criteria Query

Tags: jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I have three tables one is ItemCategory,ItemMaster and Price. I am referring  itemaCategoryId in ItemMaster table and like that referring itemmasterid in price. Now i have to display contents of price order by itemcategory id. This is my  criteria query.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Price> cq = cb.createQuery(Price.class);
    Root<Price> root = cq.from(Price.class);
    Root<ItemMaster> itemMasterRoot = cq.from(ItemMaster.class);
    Root<ItemCategory> itemCategoryRoot = cq.from(ItemCategory.class);
    Join<ItemMaster, ItemCategory> s=itemMasterRoot.join(ItemMaster_.category);     
    Join<Price,ItemMaster> y=root.join(Price_.itemMaster);

    Path<Long> itemMasterId=root.get(Price_.itemMasterId);
    cq.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get(Price_.priceMasterId), priceMasterId))
    .orderBy(cb.asc(itemMasterId));

    TypedQuery<Price> q = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
```

Above my criteria Query

Comment: Why do you have itemMasterId and itemMaster properties in Price? Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: No. Price table referring  itemmasterid only. i have to display the content of price table and order by itemcategoryid,  this is i need. But don't know properly how to join in criteria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use multiple [`from`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/AbstractQuery.html#from%28java.lang.Class%29) statements, you get the cartesian product of all entities. If you want to preserve the relationships, use join instead:

```
Root<Price> price = cq.from(Price.class);
Join<Price,ItemMaster> itemMaster = price.join(Price_.itemMaster);
Join<ItemMaster, ItemCategory> itemCategory = itemMaster.join(ItemMaster_.category);
```

However it looks like at least the second join may be useless, because you are able to access the `category` property directly using the getter, isn't it?:

```
Price aPriceResult;
ItemCategory categoryResult = aPriceResult.getItemMaster().getCategory();
```

Comment: Finally i have written like this using your code but giving error

Comment: cq.multiselect(itemCategory).where(cb.equal(root.get(Price_.priceMasterId), priceMasterId))
  .orderBy(cb.asc(itemCategory.get(ItemCategory_.id)));

Comment: Why multiselect? Use select.

Comment: finally i have got something @perissf. Thanks for response man.

Comment: This is how i have written. cq.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get(Price_.priceMasterId), priceMasterId))
  .orderBy(cb.asc(itemCategoryJoin.get(ItemCategory_.id)));

Comment: @kobe it's a [Metamodel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiup.html#gjivl)-generated entity class.